# Is it possible to define a new listener inside a listener?

Tags: java, button, swt, listener

I have an swt application on eclipse.I want to create a statement like "If x-button is not clicked, do some stuff".

```
    btnPrint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {          
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //DO STUFF    
        }
    });
```

I know that I can modify this `btnPrint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {` part as `btnPrint.addSelectionListener(SWT.Close, new SelectionAdapter() {`.But, since there are some different processes inside the widgetSelected method, I cannot change it like that.
To be clear, I want to be able to create like if (x-button is not clicked, do some stuff) inside the widgetSelected method without modifying `addSelectionListener` structure.
Is it possible to add a new listener inside a listener with a different structure?

Or how can I solve this problem?

EDIT:
The updated code is as follows:

```
    btnPrint = new ToolItem(customToolbar, SWT.NONE);
    btnPrint.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage(
            "com.meta.efatura.view", "icons/actions/print.jpg"));
    btnPrint.setText(Messages.get().getValue("Print"));
    btnPrint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {      
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    });
```

Comment: What sort of buttons are these (Push, Check, ....)?

Comment: There are approve, send, print, update and cancel buttons in the toolbar.I want to modify only the print button in the event method.

Comment: Show us how you have declared/created these buttons. The question is extremely hard to follow at present.

Comment: You must always specify one of the flags SWT.PUSH, SWT.CHECK, SWT.RADIO, SWT.SEPARATOR, or SWT.DROP_DOWN when creating a ToolItem or they won't work properly.

Comment: How are the other buttons that you want to consider created?